# Getting error "function () { [native code] }"

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and trying to make it say the error in the channel.

Instead of saying the error in the channel, it says "function () { [native code] }"

My code:

```
module.exports = {
    name:"ping",
    description: "yes ping",
    execute(message, args) {
    
        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('681210322090197005')){
            message.channel.send('wow, now thats cool! you have permissions!')


        } else {
            message.channel.send("**[Permission ERROR]** It looks like you don't have access to this command!")
            message.member.roles.add('681210323981828147').catch(message.channel.send(console.error)); // doesnt return the error in the channel!!
        }

    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to send `console.error`? What do you expect that to contain? It is a function, to log an error to the console. Not a property to get ... the last error from the console? There is no error. Do you mean something like `.catch(ex => console.error(ex))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
message.member.roles.add("681210323981828147").catch(err => {
        if(err) return message.channel.send("Error: " + err);
      });
```

This will send the error into the channel. You wanted to send `console.error`, thats not possible, because `console.error` is a function to log errors to the console.